# Eclipse deleted 3 of my projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I had a bunch of files open from 3 different projects, I opened another file to copy code into it, and then all of a sudden my tabs get closed out. 3 of my projects' code is completely gone and only thing inside each of them is an empty gen folder. Is this common, is there anything I can do to recover my code?

I got an error saying that project is 1.7 and need to fix, but this is clearly not the case. I never changed it to 1.7, and I tried doing android tools fix but that didn't work. Errors don't show up anymore

When I try and restore from local history, I see the file but when i try and restore it it says, "Cannot replace resource(resaon: state is not valid or might have expired.)."

I have about 20 hours worth of work in it, so that'd be cool if it can be recovered...

I tried restarting eclipse, and restarting my computer, both didn't work

EDIT: i'm now getting an error:

```
[2014-02-28 10:08:58 - Chat-Server-Oneway] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
```

[image]

Recent log file:

```
!SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 75 2014-02-28 09:46:33.937
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'Chat-Server-Oneway'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.BaseBuilder.abortOnBadSetup(BaseBuilder.java:326)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.build(ResourceManagerBuilder.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:47:09.275
!MESSAGE Failed to load properties file for project 'Chat-Server-Oneway'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2014-02-28 09:47:09.369
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.properties.AndroidPropertyPage.fillUi(AndroidPropertyPage.java:172)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.properties.AndroidPropertyPage.createContents(AndroidPropertyPage.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1502)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$14.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1259)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
!SESSION 2014-02-28 09:50:11.461 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-02-28 09:50:14.659
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:50:16.687
!MESSAGE projectOpenedWithWorkspace: failed to find manifest package for project BookStoreBasic

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:50:16.780
!MESSAGE projectOpenedWithWorkspace: failed to find manifest package for project Chat-Client-Oneway

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:50:16.889
!MESSAGE projectOpenedWithWorkspace: failed to find manifest package for project Chat-Server-Oneway

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:50:17.295
!MESSAGE Failed to load properties file for project 'Chat-Server-Oneway'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:50:17.451
!MESSAGE Failed to load properties file for project 'Chat-Server-Oneway'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:50:17.545
!MESSAGE Failed to load properties file for project 'Chat-Server-Oneway'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-02-28 09:50:23.550
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-02-28 09:50:23.661
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Bling'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:50:28.128
!MESSAGE Failed to load properties file for project 'BookStoreBasic'

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-02-28 09:50:28.227
!MESSAGE Failed to load properties file for project 'Chat-Client-Oneway'
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you look into the actual workspace? The project could be deleted from eclipse but I doubt that the workspace was also deleted.

Go to your default location for your workspaces and look for your projects. You could re-import them from there as desired.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, all i see is .setttings, bin, gen, .classpath, .project, doy ou have anymore ideas? i need to know if i should probably start over again pretty soon (and thank you for trying help)

Comment: Run a full system file search for one of the missing java files.

Comment: yeah, the latest version is about a week ago, which is one that i saved. is there a way to check logs?